# Eclipse Juno - TFS plug in

Tags: eclipse, eclipse-plugin

I am trying to install the TFS plug in for Eclipse Juno 4.2, the repository is http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs

Everytime, I cam up with this error:

```
An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
session context was:(profile=SDKProfile, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/eclipse/.
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable
Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/eclipse/.
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable
Unable to read repository at http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs/plugins/com.microsoft.tfs.checkinpolicies.build.nl1_11.0.0.201212121118.jar.
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable
Unable to write to repository: file:/C:/eclipse/.
Le chemin d’accès spécifié est introuvable
Unable to read repository at http://dl.microsoft.com/eclipse/tfs/plugins/com.microsoft.tfs.checkinpolicies.checkforcomments.nl1_11.0.0.201212121118.jar.
```

It seems that It cannot write to the disk ?, I change the folder location, check that no read only properties on the folders, move the folder to c:, or documents without any success

I tried with another Eclipse version too ( helios ) with same errors

Cheers

Comment: those folders are not write-protected right?

Comment: yes, not write protected

Comment: I've seen this happen when an Administrator unzips Eclipse.  If you run Eclipse as administrator can you install the plug-in?  Can you install other plug-ins from update sites?  What if you download the plugin archive zip and try to install it from your local drive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Finally, after hours of trials and failure, I ended up re installing the Java runtime, latest version is Version 7 Update 13, and Magical, it works like a charm :)

The errors message displayed is nothing but logical to find the solution, but well, it works now

thanks all

Comment: test a comment to see